# Biholomorphic mapping between two domains

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to construct a biholomorphic mapping between

\begin{align}
G:= H \setminus \{iy : y \in (0,1]\},
\end{align}

where $H:= \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{Im}(z) > 0\}$, and

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}:= \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 1\}
\end{align}.

I know about the cayley map that transforms $H$ to $\mathbb{E}$ via $z \to \frac{z-i}{z+i}$ but I struggle to handle $G$.

This question is part of an exercise. Before this question I have shown that $z \to z^2$ maps $H$ to $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0, \infty)$. Does that somehow help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that $z \to z^2$ maps $H$ to $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0, \infty)$, and the same function maps $G$ to $\mathbb{C}\setminus [-1, \infty)$.

Then $z \to z^2+1$ maps $G$ to $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0, \infty)$, and a suitable branch of the square root maps that to the upper half-plane.

Now use the Cayley map to map that to the unit disk.